# how do i fix Simbad requires Java 3D error message

Tags: java, executable-jar, robotics, java-3d

Hello I am starting with simbad and I installed Simbad1.4 and java3d1.5 but when i try to open simbad an error message occurs and it writes Simbad requires Java 3D
I have Windows 10

Comment: take the [tour] read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello. I advise you to modify your classpath to include Java3D 1.6.2 instead of Java3D 1.5. Java3D 1.5 is obsolete and is absolutely not guaranteed to work under Windows 10. You can follow my tutorial: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/ I haven't deeply looked at Simbad, maybe you'll have to modify it a bit to make it work, it seems to be unmaintained since 2007.

Comment: Simbad uses Ant as a build tool, you can use my script as a source of inspiration to include Java3D into the JAR to build an executable JAR containing Simbad and Java3D: https://sourceforge.net/p/tuer/git/ci/master/tree/pre_beta/build.xml